# Reverse not found

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.7 and I have this URL pattern:

```
url(r'^account/unsubscribe/(?P<user_id>[^/.]+)/(?P<token>[\w.:\-_=]+)$', views.unsubscribe, name='account-unsubscribe')
```

And I have this in my project code:

```
def create_unsubscribe_link(self):
    email, token = self.user.email_notifications.make_token().split(":", 1)
    user_id = TelespineUser.objects.get(email=email)
    return reverse('account-unsubscribe',
                   kwargs={'user_id': user_id, 'token': token, })
```

Why do I get this while calling create_unsubscribe_link?:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account-unsubscribe' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'token': '1ehbA0:czK8xR8IGiGu7WdEuYRkYigXBzI', 'user_id': <TelespineUser: name: demo@telespine.com, id: 1>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/v1/account/unsubscribe/(?P<user_id>[^/.]+)/(?P<token>[\\w.:\\-_=]+)$']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user_id` parameter is a TelespineUser object not its `id` parameter.

You need to change it like this:

```
def create_unsubscribe_link(self):
    email, token = self.user.email_notifications.make_token().split(":", 1)
    user_id = TelespineUser.objects.get(email=email).id
    return reverse('account-unsubscribe',
                   kwargs={'user_id': user_id, 'token': token, })
```

Comment: That's true. Thank you!